# AngularJS - Unknown provider: groupByFilterProvider <- groupByFilter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a array of object. I need to group the data by one field and show the result in an HTML table.

INPUT :

```
[
    {
        id: "559e2bbc9a496034557d6d84",
        text: "Data Sources",
        topParentId: "559e2bbc9a496034557d6d84",
        topParentText: "Data Sources"
    },
    {
        id: "559e2bbc9a496034557d6d83",
        text: "Applications",
        topParentId: "559e2bbc9a496034557d6d83",
        topParentText: "Applications"
    },
    {
        id: "559e2bbc9a496034557d6d82",
        text: "Analytics",
        topParentId: "559e2bbc9a496034557d6d83",
        topParentText: "Applications"
    }
]
```

**From this I need to create an HTML table like this (grouping data by topParentId):**

```
Group            |       Tags
Data Sources     |      Data Sources
Applications     |      Applications   Analytics
```

**So far I have done this:**

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Group</th>
                <th>Tags</th>
              </tr >
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="tag in topic.tags | groupBy: 'topParentId'">
                <td>{{tag.topParentText}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>{{tag.text}}</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

But after running this code, I am getting  `Unknown provider: groupByFilterProvider <- groupByFilter` error.

**I am using AngularJs 1.2**

Comment: Can you share `groupBy` filter declaration

Comment: did you include angular.filter? https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Comment: @rmuller: I was wondering if there is any inbuilt feature. I have not included angular-filter

Comment: @Chandermani: I thought groupBy is available out of the box.

Comment: @SharpCoder orderBy is available out of the box, but not groupBy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As mentionned by @jhadesdev `orderBy` is available out of the box, but not `groupBy`.
It is included in [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby)