# ngRepeat:dupes Duplicate Key in Repeater

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,val) in names" >
{{val.name}}
< /li>
```

while using ng-repeat values are getting fetched and when i try to refresh the values cannot be inserted and i am getting the following error in resources.

```
[{"name":"a","$$hashKey":"object:3"},{"name":"b","$$hashKey":"object:4"},{"name":"c","$$hashKey":"object:5"},{"name":"c","$$hashKey":"object:6"},{"name":"c","$$hashKey":"object:12"},{"name":"c","$$hashKey":"object:14"},{"name":"c"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
<button ng-click="pushData()">Click me</button>
</form>
<div ng-repeat="values in names track by $index">
{{values.name}}
</div>
```

controller

```
$scope.names = [];
$scope.pushData = function(){
$scope.names.push({'name':$scope.name});    
}
```

Comment: output: a b c c c c c

Comment: now please try refreshing and again enter the same data

Comment: it display all name values present in $scope.names= [{"name":"a","$$hashKey":"object:3"},{"name":"b","$$hashKey":"object:4"},{"name":"c","$$hashKey":"object:5"},{"name":"c","$$hashKey":"object:6"},{"name":"c","$$hashKey":"object:12"},{"name":"c","$$hashKey":"object:14"},{"name":"c"},{"name":"c","$$hashKey":"object:12"},{"name":"c","$$hashKey":"object:14"},{"name":"c"}] object.

Comment: after refreshing can u able to insert data in the same array

Comment: its temp array after refreshing data get erased. use DataBase

Answer (score 0):

You are telling your `ngRepeat` to iterate over keys of an object but what you have is a list/array. So, change to:

```
<div ng-repeat="val in names">
    {{val.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: my array structure is like this  $scope.names.push({'name':$scope.name});

Comment: you need to show your array. Please post the array sample along with data.

Comment: when i insert the value its is getting inserted [{"name":"a"}] but when i try to refresh the page and insert value it is not getting inserted and throwing error[{"name":"b","$$hashKey":"object:4"},{"name":"c","$$hashKey":"object:3"},]

Answer (score 0):

you should group your items by theirs name not to have duplicates, please try this one

```
<li ng-repeat="val in names | groupBy: val.name" >
  {{val.name}}
< /li>
```

Comment: Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: groupByFilterProvider <- groupByFilter

Comment: please try this - | groupBy: 'name'

Comment: in case of having any further issue with groupBy filter, please check whether you have included angular.filter in your application, also please visit this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338447/unknown-provider-groupbyfilterprovider-groupbyfilter